# Range of Values Represented by 1's Complement with 7 bits

Tags: ones-complement

Assume that there are 7-bits that are available to store a binary number. Specify the range of numbers that can be represented by 1's Complement. I found that the range for 2's Complement is -64 ≤ 0 ≤ 63. How do I do this for 1's Complement?

Answer (score 3):

In 2s complement method of representation of binary numbers, for signed numbers, the range of numbers that can be represented is -2^(N-1) - (2^(N-1)-1) for an N-bit number.
That is why you have obtained the range -64 - 63 for a 7 bit binary number.

Now in the case of 1s Complement method of representation, the range of numbers that can be represented is -(2^(N-1)-1) - (2^(N-1)-1).
And this will result in a range of -63 - 63 for a 7 bit number in 1s complement representation.